# django 1.7 how to migration with existed tables

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

I upgrade to django 1.7
and need to deal with migration

My database already exists tables

Here is my step :

1.I delete the `migration` in django app  `test`
2.I remove south(from INSTALLED APPS ) in django settings.py
3.run   `python manage.py makemigrations test`

```
  Migrations for 'test':
    0001_initial.py:
      - Create model Person
      - Create model Book
      - Create model Artical
```

4. run `python manage.py migrate test`

   Operations to perform:
       Apply all migrations: test
     Running migrations:
       Applying test.0001_initial... FAKED

is it right???
How to do migration if I already have tables?
Please guide me Thank you

Comment: Well forget my first comment. Please read this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: you need to revert the models.py to its state before you made changes to the models, then `makemigrations` and `migrate` as above... then apply the changes to models.py and repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is right if the tables that exist in your database have the same structure as your current models (i.e. you haven't modified your models.py file after you applied you last migrations with South). If that's the case, you can proceed without worries.

If the structure **is** different, you can try different approaches:

- Create the needed migrations manually. You will have to write your own migration with the needed modifications. [Here](http://django.zone/posts/django-17-migrations-troubleshooting) you can find some example code of a migrations file for altering or adding fields and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/migration-operations/) you have the complete reference of the methods you can call
- Modify your database manually with phpmyadmin, raw sql or the method you prefer.
- Do a `python manage.py dumpdata app1 app2 app3 > data.json`, remove the db, create it again and to a `python manage.py loaddata data.json`. This may raise some errors because the data you saved was with the old structure, you will have to deal with each error.
- Or the least preferred, if the data you had is not needed, just remove the db and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it.

The reason the first migration is faked is because your tables are already created:

> Run python manage.py migrate. Django will see that the tables for the
>   initial migrations already exist and mark them as applied without
>   running them.

From the [documentation on upgrading from `South`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south).